# how can I create a new admin page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, backend

I need to have new backend page in my magento2 admin panel but I have no idea how I can create it with a db installer.
I have already created the db table and a backend page but have no idea how can I show the data in the backend page

Comment: Please update your question more details.

Comment: Check this :http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html